# Datepicker onSelect to format new date range

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 2 datepickers, one is a fromDate and one is a toDate. I can highlight the range from the fromDate to the toDate successfully in beforeShowDay(), but I need it to highlight when new values are selected. This triggers the onSelect statement. Is there a way to either:

1) trigger the beforeShowDay again? or

2) get all the dates of the new range and apply a css class to them?

```
 beforeShowDay: function(date){
                        if (date >= initialFromDate && date <= initialToDate) {
                            return [true, 'ui-individual-date', ''];
                        }
                        else {
                            return [true, '', ''];
                        }
                    },
 onSelect: function (dateText, obj) {

                        var fromDate = new Date(dateText);
                        var toDate = $(".dateDiv2").datepicker('getDate');

     **get individual dates? 
       if (individualdate >= fromDate && individualDate <= toDate)
       apply css class or formatting to individualDate**

},
```

[image: The picture gives the generated css and html for the datepicker]

[image]

[image]

Comment: using the datepickers refresh at the end of the onSelect statement does not work.

Comment: Could you set this up in jsfiddle ?

Comment: There is way too much to put into jsfiddle

Comment: i tried, but it doesn't look right in jsfiddle. it looks and works right in a browser.

Comment: Just in `beforeShowDay` change `initialFromDate` and `initialToDate` to `$(".fromDateSelector").datepicker('getDate')` and `$(".toDateSelector").datepicker('getDate')`. Cause first check if this values exists. And in `onSelect` just `$( ".fromDateSelector" ).datepicker( "refresh" );` and `$( ".toDateSelector" ).datepicker( "refresh" );`. No need to use global variables, you can simple get selected date and refresh datepicker.

Comment: that works, but it has to have an initial value, otherwise getDate has nothing to find on the first load.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this successfully with a datepicker for a from date and a datepicker for a to date, so I modified it for one datepicker. Here is the code:

```
 $(function () {
            var today = new Date();
            var thisYear = (today).getFullYear();
            var fromDate = '1/1/2000'   //this is the initial from date to set the datepicker range
            var toDate = '1/7/2000' // this is the initial to date to set the datepicker range

//... initialize datepicker....
  },
  beforeShowDay: function(date){
        //if the date is in range
        if (date >= fromDate && date <= toDate) { 
           return [true, 'ui-individual-date', '']; //applies a css class to the range
         }
         else {
            return [true, '', ''];
          }
    },
   onSelect: function (dateText, obj) {

//sets the new range to be loaded on refresh call, assumes last click is the toDate              
     fromDate = toDate; 
     toDate = new Date(dateText); 

    $(".classDp1").datepicker("refresh"); 
    $(".classDp2").datepicker("refresh"); 
  },
```

Every time you refresh the beforeShowDay function is called with the new fromDate and toDate range. Having the variables outside the function and modifying them within enables the highlighting from the css to be applied on each click.

Answer (score 0):

[Link on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ostapische/hpf0t1xj/)

HTML:

```
<div id="dateFrom"></div>  
<div id="dateTo"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div#dateFrom, div#dateTo { display: inline-block; }  
.ui-individual-date { background: yellow; }
```

JS:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#dateFrom, #dateTo" ).datepicker( {
        beforeShowDay: function( date ){
            var initialFromDate, initialToDate;
            initialFromDate = $("#dateFrom").datepicker('getDate');
            initialToDate = $("#dateTo").datepicker('getDate');
            if ( date >= initialFromDate && date <= initialToDate ) {
                return [ true, 'ui-individual-date', '' ];
            } else {
                return [ true, '', '' ];
            }
        },
        onSelect: function ( dateText, obj ) {
            $( "#dateFrom" ).datepicker( "refresh" );
            $( "#dateTo" ).datepicker( "refresh" );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Just in beforeShowDay change `initialFromDate` and `initialToDate` to `$("#dateFrom").datepicker('getDate')` and `$("#dateTo").datepicker('getDate')`.
And in `onSelect` use `$( "#dateFrom" ).datepicker( "refresh" );` and `$( "#dateTo" ).datepicker( "refresh" );`.