# Bootstrap Datepicker + Highlight Days List + Reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, date, datepicker

I try work with datepicker, I have a **select with accounts**, when selected read days database and highlight.

But, if I select another account, not clear highlights to set new days highlighted from another account. Understand?

[image: Days highlighted:]

I want refresh to clear highlighted days.

```
var dias = "10/05/2017, 10/13/2017";
var matriz = dias.split(",");
var tamanho = matriz.length;

var Asdatas = {};
for(i=0; i<tamanho; i++){
    Asdatas[ new Date(matriz[i]) ] = new Date(matriz[i]);
}
$('.input-append.date').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var highlight = Asdatas[date];
        if( highlight ) {
            return 'highlight';
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
});
```

This script works only once. And if execute again not set highlights and continue show old highlights.

Comment: Could you tell me what Boostrap Datepicker version are you using?

Comment: Version 1.4 bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: Problem without solution.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29085489/datepicker-onselect-to-format-new-date-range?rq=1 where they use the onSelect: datepicker().refresh to call the beforeShowDay again